# Get MySql data an put into an multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Can be PHP or Mysql  solution...
I want to be able to store some data that has been selected from a mysql database in a php array. So far, I have only been able put in a "fake" array

```
$SQL = "SELECT *  FROM continents RIGTH JOIN Country ON Country_Continents = continents_ID";
       while ($CONT = mysql_fetch_array($DataSet)){
            $array_cont[] = $CONT["continents_name"];
            $country_ID_rry [] = $CONT;
         }
```

Then I get an array per continent and i the continent array get the countries name..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => America
            [continents_name] => America
            [1] => 3
            [country_id] => 3
            [2] => México
            [country_name] => México
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SouthAmérica
            [continents_name] => SouthAmerica
            [1] => 2
            [country_id] => 2
            [2] => Argentina
            [country_name] => Argentina
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SotuhAmerica
            [continents_name] => SouthAmerica
            [1] => 5
            [country_id] => 5
            [2] => Venezuela
            [country_name] => Venezuela
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => SouthAmerica
            [continents_name] => SouthAmerica
            [1] => 6
            [country_id] => 6
            [2] => Colombia
            [country_name] => Colombia
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Caribe
            [continents_name] => Caribe
            [1] => 1
            [country_id] => 1
            [2] => Cuba
            [country_name] => Cuba
        )

)
```

but I want something like that...

```
Array
(
    [SouthAmerica] => Array
        (
            [0] => Argentina
            [1] => Brazil
            [2] => Colombia
        )

    [NorthAmerica] => Array
        (
            [0] => Usa
            [1] => Mexico
            [2] => Canada
        )

    [Europa] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ukraine
            [1] => Germany
            [2] => England
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

- mysqli_fetch_array()
- PDOStatement::fetch()

But the general idea (fetching just the associtive array):

```
while ($CONT = mysql_fetch_assoc($DataSet)){
    $Pais_ID_rry[$CONT["continents_name"]][] = $CONT['country_name'];
}
```

In addition, if you only want *Continent* and *Country* names:

```
SELECT continents_name, country_name FROM continents . . .
```